# NTP server acting weird

Tags: linux, ntp

I have an NTP server on the network that is acting very weird.

I have not changed any of the ntpd.conf settings. Its a debian box and I did a regular install.

I have an NTP client on the network. If I run ntpq -p "192.168.1.5" I get "timed out, nothing received". However, If I look on wireshark, I can clearly see UDP communication between the two hosts, the client requesting, and the server responding. I can also ping between the host and server just fine.

I have no firewall rules, I did iptables -F on both machines.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. This is very bizarre.

Also, this worked yesterday fine and just started acting up today. I have rebooted both boxes, looked in /var/log/messages, and haven't seen anything unusual.

Comment: Is your NTP server running on a virtual machine? Please post the NTP config files for both the server and the client.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in a recent package update. You could try reverting to the old version of NTP with `apt-get -t=wheezy ntp` and then maybe `apt-get hold ntp` if you want to keep it that way until the next version comes out.

Keeping track of when the next version comes out is a little trickier however, and requires a lot of manual checking on your part.